# Apply angularjs controller functionality on dynamically loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax

I am new to AngularJs and I got stuck with a situation where I need your help.

I am loading content using `$http service` within an angularjs controller and on loading the content I am replacing the new content (with the new controller) from `Ajax` with the whole currently working controller and I am doing this replacing part using jQuery .html() function. Now the issue is that the content loaded perfectly but the functionality of new controller is not working at all.

As I told that I am new here, please guide me if I am following right technique and what would be the solution to this problem or is there any new option to do task.

I also tried loading the content with directive but after using it, the loaded content won't perform any functionality at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me.

```
angular.bootstrap($('body'), ['app']);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to compile the new content (with new controller) before replacing it. you can use $compile service for that.